# General term to cover piano fingerings, trombone slide positions, Theremin hand positions, etc

Tags: terminology, fingering

Is there a general term to describe the concepts referred by "fingering", "(slide) position", perhaps other such words, that describe the specific manipulations of an instrument to produce pitches? And if yes, what is that word?

More generally, how does one describe the underlying concept? My phrase "manipulations to produce pitches" seems inelegant at best, if not outright baffling in its intended meaning.

---

**UPDATE**

This question was prompted by trying to think up a tag synonym for "fingering" that would apply to instruments like trombone. Currently (as of 11 Feb 2021), there is a tag called [fingering-and-positions](/questions/tagged/fingering-and-positions) available, but not proposed as a synonym.

Comment: If I were trying to write about that I would probably describe those actions as “pitch selection” or “note selection”. Not very elegant, I admit.

Comment: @ToddWilcox Yeah, it's sticky. "Pitch/note selection" makes me think of composing/improvising as opposed to the mechanical aspect.

Comment: I note, that this would also cover fingerboard positions for violin family, but am afraid the even in the restricted form the asked concept is quite broad and there may be no term for it. Interestingly *muscle memory* as the source for doing all that correctly, is pretty established.

Comment: Maybe something related to "modulation"?

Comment: Does "Technique" work?

Comment: @MattPutnam Possibly, although that term covers a lot of territory compared to, say, "fingering", which is a specific area of technique. It's worth consideration.

Comment: I think it would be hard to cover all the ways instruments are manipulated to alter pitch with one term, that would not have ambiguity.  For instance- french horn players not only finger the valves with their left hand; they also change the pitch with their right hand in the bell.  Would both hands be covered by such a term?  Seems to me that any such term would be too ambiguous.

Comment: @ScottWallace Is the bell-hand part of the basic note production? If yes, then it would fall under the term I'm looking for (or inventing); if no, then it would fall under another term, like "technique".

Comment: @Aaron - Yes, putting the hand in the bell of a french horn lowers the pitch, but it also alters the timbre. Would your term be limited to hands?  What about the recorder player's technique of stopping the end of the instrument with their knee?  Or lipping notes up or down, as all wind players do? Or vibrato?  I don't see how you can draw a clear boundary between "basic note production" and "technique".

Comment: You could try "pitch control".

Comment: *Piano fingerings* are explicitly mentioned, but have no influence on the pitch?!

Answer (score 1):

The first word that came to mind is simply *technique.*

I know that can include lots of other things beside pitch, but *fingering technique* or *manual technique* seems straight forward for what you are hinting at.

FWIW, it's not entirely clear what your after. You specified pitch and implied *hand*, *manual* technique. Does that mean voice is excluded? Hand in a horn bell, included? Percussion stick technique, in or out based on pitch/non-pitched?

If it's *manual technique* your are after, I think just say that and don't necessarily limit it to pitch.

Comment: Good point about the clarity issue. I've updated the OP to indicate how the question originated.

Answer (score 0):

This article http://www.donaldsauter.com/guitar-fingering-notation.htm uses term "performance indication". I don't believe it's widely used, but seems accurate.

Comment: That term is typically used to describe any instruction related to how a piece is to be performed. Although it's used in relation to fingering in the example you found, the term is more general.

Comment: @Aaron I think instructions are called "performance notes". Anyway, OP asked for a more general term for "fingering". However, as I don't believe the term is widely used, it may not be understood if not introduced properly.

Comment: OP is me. Performance indication and performance note are overlapping terms.

Comment: @Aaron oops! Right. I gave the best answer I could. But possibly the term you're asking for doesn't exist, or there is no single, widely agreed upon term.

Comment: The term not existing does seem to be the conclusion we're headed toward, in which case something like your suggestion may win the day, so to speak. The underlying motivation is a synonym for the "fingering" tag to cover the more general case. We'll see...